# Iphone Scrollview Question

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scrollview

i am quit new at iphone development and trying to make a photo collage software while learning it. Right now i have a lil problem and hope you can help me out.

I have an UiviewController with a view in it, in this view i have 7 scrollviews with uiimagevies in them for zooming and scollign images within these scrollviews.

All that works well but now i want to make these 7 scrollviews dragable and maybe if possible zoomable (so that the image within the given scroolview zoom together with the scrollview).

It should be possible to drag them all around the screen and if possible even overlap them
and by the way rotating would be great ;-) hope that is not to much asked for.

Would be great if someone can help me out with this..

Answer (score 0):

Well you've got to decide on some other choice here because the functionality you are asking for overlaps, and you can't ask the app to magically know which the user wants to do. What I mean by this is that when you touch and drag within a scroll view, it's going to try to scroll itself, rather than drag the entire scroll view around.

As for rotation and zooming - that gets more complicated, because you start dealing with vector math and the like. You can check out my question on rotation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303030/two-finger-rotation-gesture-on-the-iphone). The link I gave you has the code to get both rotation and zooming to work.